# Convert time to a different time zone in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am saving order details with server time which is "Central Daylight Time" timezone as Unix time stamp. So order_date is the server time. What I need is, convert that to Korean time. Below is the query which I have used.

```
SELECT 
  `order_date`,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(`order_date`),
  CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(order_date), 'US/Central', 'Asia/Seoul') 
FROM
  my_orders 
WHERE order_id="123"
```

This gives null result for the converted date. Is there anything I have to change with the CONVERT_TZ parameter? Or there is any other better methods for this?

Comment: I have also tried   CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.mdate), 'CDT', 'KST')  too. But still NULL results.

Comment: I think my problem is, time zone table not loaded into mysql.

Answer (score 5):

I hope below answer helpful to you.

```
CONVERT_TZ(Date_Column,"+00:00",Your_Offset)
```

In this Your_Offset = "+5:30" (+5:30 is for india because GST+5:30).

You can also refer [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manually converting timestamps in your query, store them as MySQL's `timestamp` type, and use the native timestamp support in whatever API you're using to access the database.  (In JDBC, for example, you'd use the `ResultSet.getTimestamp` method.)  This should take care of time-zone issues in the database automatically, and give you a timestamp object in your application that you can display in whatever time zone you want.

Time zones are a presentation issue.  The database shouldn't be formatting timestamps into specific time zones; let the application do that.

Comment: I need to pass the query to create a grid, which is a third party application. There I cant find the time zone change option. I think my problem is, time zone table not loaded into mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Try and convert the time using Php code and not on Mysql.

Object oriented style

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```

Procedural style

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2000-01-01', timezone_open('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```

The above examples will output:

2000-01-01 00:00:00+12:00

2000-01-01 01:45:00+13:45

Comment: I need to pass the query to create a grid, which is a third party application. There I cant find the time zone change option. I think my problem is, time zone table not loaded into mysql.

Comment: That is where php comes in or were you not using php in your code?